# What is the sugya for wall-writing?

Tags: shabbat, talmud-bavli, maseches-shabbos

Where is the sugya in Shabbat for the prohibition of reading text written on a wall on shabbat? I learned this the other week, but I cannot remember the daf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you were learning [Shabbos 149a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=149&format=text), "מאי בינייהו א"ב דכתב אכותל ומידלי" regarding counting the guests and their portions on Shabbos.

Comment: Thanks, @AvrohomYitzchok, we were learning from photocopies which were missing the top of the daf.